# django rest framework get() returned more than one object though filter() method is used

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In `model.py`, I've two models

```
class student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    session = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    college = models.ForeignKey(to='college', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'student'


class semester(models.Model):
    semester = models.IntegerField()
    student = models.ForeignKey(to='student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sgpa = models.FloatField()
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_fail = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'semester'
```

Serializer classes looks like

```
class SemesterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.semester
        fields = ('id', 'semester', 'sgpa', 'grade', 'is_fail',)

class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.student
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'registration_number', 'college', 'session',)
```

and `views.py` contains

```
class SemesterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):    
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'semester' in self.kwargs:
            return models.semester.objects.filter(semester=self.kwargs['semester'])
        else:
            return models.semester.objects.all()

    lookup_field = 'semester'
    serializer_class = serializer.SemesterSerializer
```

url patterns are

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('semester', views.SemesterViewSet, base_name='semester')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

When I tried to visit `url/semester/8`, `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception raised and showes `get() returned more than one semester -- it returned 2!` error message. Here I've not used any `get()` method. Why this is happening and what is solution? I need to show all result of semester.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `lookup_field` from view or change it to `lookup_field = 'id'`
The error is because while you calling a `retrieve()` method, inside it invokes a `get_object()` which is sililar to the query similar to

```
semester.objects.get(semester=semester.objects.get(id=8).semester)
```

```
semester.objects.get(lookup_field=parameter)
```

**example:**

```
semester.objects.get(semester=8)
```

So, if there is more than 1 semester instances have same `semester` value, it would raise an error

**UPDATE-1**
Try to override `retrieve()` method in view,

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class SemesterViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'semester' in self.kwargs:
            return semester.objects.filter(semester=self.kwargs['semester'])
        else:
            return semester.objects.all()

    lookup_field = 'semester'
    serializer_class = SemesterSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs): # Change is here <<
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Comment: `self.kwargs['semester']` needs `semester`, so I can't remove lookup_field as `semester`

Comment: So, you are trying to retrieve all instances based on the `semester` value ?